# Sending image from javascript to html

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
var img = "img1.jpg";
$("#img1").attr("src",img);
</script>
<body>
<img id="img1" src = "">
</body>
```

I want to replace src in img tag in html by the variable img from javascript.
But the code does not work. Can anyone help me out ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: How does the code 'not work'? Please expand.

Comment: When your JS gets executed, the element doesn't exist yet (it's defined below). Move the JS to the bottom or call it after the DOM has loaded completely

Answer (score -1):

try inside document ready,

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  var img = "img1.jpg";
  $("#img1").attr("src",img);

});

</script>
```

Comment: can you post your full template

Comment: Thanks. Your code helped at last. Besides the lines you mentioned I added this extra line.                                                                            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>